# R multinomial regression with svyVGAM after propensity score matching with MatchThem

Tags: r, regression, r-mice, multinomial, propensity-score-matching

I try to perform a multinomial regression with svy_vglm function from svyVGAM package after propensity score matching. I used matchthem function from MatchThem package in R.

```
model <- with(matchthem object, svy_vglm(outcome~exposure, family = multinomial(refLevel="0")), cluster = TRUE)
```

The script runs well I think but I get a warning message :
`In vglm.fitter(x = x, y = y, w = w, offset = offset, Xm2 = Xm2,  : some quantities such as z, residuals, SEs may be inaccurate due to convergence at a half-step`

The problem is that: I can't obtain the summarized results.
a summary(pool(model)) isn't applicable for objects of class svy_vglm, and I get error message when I try a function MIcombine(model) or MIextract(model, fun=vcov) :
`Error in vcov.default(X[[i]], ...) :  object does not have variance-covariance matrix`

Do you know how I can pooled or summarized the estimations ? May be should I used others functions to pool or correct the variance-covariance matrix ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you make your post reproducible? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example